# Why am I getting a type error when converting to python scalers?

Tags: python

In the code I have the following - am I trying to create a LSTM network and the error is happening in the `difference()` function.

Here is the func:

```py
def difference(dataset, interval=1):
    diff = list()
    for i in range(interval, len(dataset)):
        value = dataset[i] - dataset[i - interval]
        diff.append(value)
    return Series(diff)
```

This gave me the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

And after some research found that this was the solution:

```py
def difference(dataset, interval=1):
    diff = list()
    for i in range(interval, len(dataset)):
        value = int(dataset[i]) - int(dataset[i - interval])
        diff.append(value)
    return Series(diff)
```

Then I got this error:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

So I found a solution that was suggesting I create a vector so I made the function:

```py
def difference(dataset, interval=1):
    diff = list()
    for i in range(interval, len(dataset)):
        vector = numpy.vectorize(numpy.float)
        value = int(dataset[i]) - int(dataset[i - interval])
        value = vector(value)
        diff.append(value)
    return Series(diff)
```

But this still gives the error, any help with this? Thanks

Comment: Please clarify what you intend the ```difference``` function to do.   You are clearly subtracting strings; but what does it mean?    What would  "A" - "B" mean?

Comment: instead of `numpy.float` try `numpy.float_`

Comment: Can you tell us what `dataset` is? (`type(dataset)`, and if a numpy array, then `dataset.shape` and `dataset.dtype`)

Comment: @ewong The function will make the data stationary and transform the values into differences. The values can only range from 1 to -1

Comment: @Amadan it is a csv file defined as: read_csv('solar_power_consumption.csv', header=0, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, squeeze=True, date_parser=parser)

Comment: So, it's a `pandas.DataFrame`? Then please report what `dataset.dtypes` and `dataset.columns`  say.